# EasyApache 4 Migration Issue

Tags: apache-httpd, mysql, php, webserver

One of server is hosting several domains with their wepages mostly in php. Server was running eayapache3 with php5.5. One of the domain asked to enable php5.6 recently. So we migrated the server from easyapache3 to easyapache4. Server hit full disk space today & apache stopped serving. Now we removed old backups to make space as a temporary measure. Now some domains are loading, and some are displaying http 500 error.

Please can someone guide us?
FYI: I've restarted all relevant services, especially http & mysql.

Comment: I got this link to solve http 500 error here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-common-http-error-codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check error_log for any messages being logged when you try to load the domain that shows error 500.

Issue `tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`, and then try to load the domain, and see what messages are being logged when you are doing that, you might get some messages related to permissions, or missing php extensions.

If you have migrated from EasyApache 3 to EasyApache 4, then it is likely possible that some php extensions were not installed in EasyApache 4